Separation of Variables Method for PDEs with Arbitary Functions as Solutions
I try to use the separation of variables method to solve the following PDE:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x, y) - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x, y) = 0 \,\,\,\,\,(1)$
Assuming $f(x, y) = X(x)Y(y)$ and substituting this into the above, I obtain
$\frac{X'(x)}{X(x)} = \frac{Y'(y)}{Y(y)} = \lambda \,\,\,\,\,(2)$
where $\lambda$ is the separation constant. From the above we have two ODEs:
$X'(x) - \lambda X(x) = 0 \,\,\,\,\,(3)$
$Y'(y) - \lambda Y(y) = 0 \,\,\,\,\,(4)$
By solving the two ODEs and multiplying them, I get the following general solution to $(1)$:
$f(x, y) = e^{\lambda(x + y)} \,\,\,\,\,(5)$
where $\lambda$ is in fact an arbitrary constant. But I find that the solution above is not general enough. In fact, the following is also a solution to $(1)$:
$f(x, y) = g(x + y) \,\,\,\,\,(6)$
where $g$ represents an arbitrary function. How can I deduce the solution $(6)$ from $(5)$?

Separation of variables points to simple solutions which, in turn, often can be used to construct a much broader class of solutions, as in this case.

Thank you for your reply. But what are the techniques for constructing a much broader class of solutions? Is there any reference materials?

Well, I know how to use the method of characteristics to solve a 1st order linear PDE like (1) above, and in fact, by using this method, I can find the solution in (6) directly. But my question is how we can deduce the solution (6) from (5).

As you observed equation $(5)$ isn't the general solution of the PDE.
$$f_\lambda (x, y) = e^{\lambda(x + y)} \tag 5$$
Any linear combination of $f_\lambda (x, y)$ with various $\lambda$ is solution of the PDE.
More general discrete form :
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{\forall\lambda} C_\lambda\:f_\lambda (x, y) = \sum_{\forall\lambda} C_\lambda\:e^{\lambda(x + y)}$$
$C_\lambda$ are arbitrary constants.
Or more general :
$$f(x,y)=\int C(\lambda)\:f_\lambda (x, y) d\lambda= \int C(\lambda)\:e^{\lambda(x + y)}d\lambda$$
$C(\lambda)$ is an arbitrary function.
This last expression shows that $f(x,y)$ is an arbitrary function of $(x+y)$. Thus
$$f(x,y)=g(x+y)$$
$g$ is an arbitrary function.
Note : This isn't so simple in the majority of cases of first order PDE. Finding the general solution requires more advanced method than separation of variables. See the method of characteristics.
